# Access saved instance state outside onCreate() and onRestoreInstanceState()

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle, android-orientation, activity-lifecycle

Is it possible to access the saved instance state passed to `onCreate()` from any other method in the activity?

I'm storing a `CameraPosition` in `onSaveInstanceState()`, and I need to access it in `onMapReady()` which is called asynchronously when the Google Map is ready. Right now I'm pulling the `CameraPosition` out of the bundle in `onCreate` and saving it in a member variable, but perhaps there is a way of accessing everything that was passed as the `savedInstanceState` to the `onCreate()` method from anywhere in the activity lifecycle?

Comment: I don't think there's anything that supports this in `Activity`. Since it is not your `Bundle`, I would be hesitant to hold onto the `Bundle` directly (e.g., stuff that in a field in `onCreate()`). I think your current approach is reasonable.